# VSCode Prettier setting configs to match "npx standard --fix"

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

How would one change their Prettier settings for VSCode to match the code styling of [npm's standard package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard) code styling?

My settings differ from the updates done by the `npx standard --fix` command from the package.
Is there a config file for Prettier that matches the package's code styling?

When running the `npx standard --fix` command, things like end of array commas, newlining, etc. are different from what is automated when saving a .js/.css file using Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

When using the following packages:

- [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint)
- [eslint-config-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-prettier)
- [eslint-config-standard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-standard)
- [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier)
- [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier)

With an `.eslintrc.json` file containing:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "standard", // https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard#usage
    "plugin:prettier/recommended" // required by eslint-plugin-prettier, must be last; auto-configures prettier
  ],
}
```

With a `.prettierrc.json` file containing:

```json
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

There should be no conflicts when you format your files using `eslint`, e.g., `npx eslint . --fix`, and your files will be formatted appropriately using standard and prettier rules.